# NLTK Find occurrences of a word within 5 words (left/right) of context words in a corpus

Tags: python, nltk, text-mining

I used scrapy to crawl a website to get thousands of .txt files, each containing a text in natural language (description of a drug-induced experience). The name of each of these files is a unique number.
I also have a .csv file with metadata associated with each of these unique numbers (i.e. I have a column for text_number, and other columns for the metadata corresponding to this particular number). One of the category of metadata is a dosage number (in mg).

Here is what I'm trying to do:

1. Find which .txt files contain an occurrence of a specific word ('self') within 5 words (left and right) of one of 100 specific context words (I have a precise list).
2. Get the average dosage number (from the metadata) of .txt files singled out in the first step, in order to compare it to the average dosage number of all .txt files.

I really don't know how to proceed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a regular expression might be a good solution to this.
They're fast, and you have a lot of data.
Not sure what the best way to do this would be, but here's one solution.

Say your target word ('self') and your list of context words looks like this:

```
target_word = 'self'
context_words = ['one', 'hundred', 'context', 'words']
#mine is much shorter than yours! ;)
```

Then you can create a regular expression that expects words to be separated by spaces.
I used one pattern for when the context word is before and one for when the context word is after, then combined them with an or ('|').
Not sure if that's necessary, just couldn't easily think of another way.

```
import re
matches_up_to_4_words = '( [^ ]*){0,4} ?'
matches_context_word = '(' + '|'.join(context_words) + ')'
matches_target_word = target_word
context_before = matches_context_word + matches_up_to_4_words + matches_target_word
context_after = matches_target_word + matches_up_to_4_words + matches_context_word
pattern = re.compile('(' + context_before + '|' + context_after + ')')

matching_metadata = []
for filename in filenames:
    filestring = open(filename, 'rb').read()
    ## you can tokenize here for better word segmentation
    ## http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html 
    if re.search(pattern, filestring):
        print "the target word appeared near a context word"
        ## get the metadata
        metadata = get_the_metadata(filename, filestring)
        matching_metadata.append(metadata)
```

Then you have the metadata stored that you can work with.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm sorry in advance if this is a rookie mistake (I'm quite new to python and coding in general), but when I try your code with "for filename in filenames", I get the following error: NameError: name 'filenames' is not defined

Comment: I've also tried to replace it with `for filename in os.listdir("txt"):`, knowing that I have a /txt folder with the texts where my code is, but this gets me another error: `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sample.txt'`

Comment: Oh, um... I don't know what your directory structure is like, so I just used a variable. You can do something like `filenames=paste('data-directory/', 1:100, '.txt', sep='')` or whatever matches your directory structure to get the list of filenames.